# SQL- limit number of words in a varchar field

Tags: sql, create-table

I'm creating a database, and I would like to limit one of the table's fields to contain no more than 50 words but I'm not sure what is the way to create this constraint....?

Comment: Specify dbms used. (Probably a product specific answer.)

Comment: Seems like this constraint should be in your application layer. That being said, it entirely depends on how you define a word. "Is.This.One.Word"? "Or only with spaces"? "What if,you add a comma?" "What about dashed-words or words in разных языках"?

Comment: Just a single space.... I do know how to implement it in the application layer, but I thought that maybe there is a way to count the number of spaces in the input with a constraint...

Comment: @mmm You could calculate it something like.. `len(mycol) - len(replace(mycol,' ','')) + 1` and then add a CHECK constraint that the result <= 50. Though it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @mmm Because any update that touches that field will need to do a sub-optimal calculation to check the length. It will throw a constraint error when changing it, making it harder to provide the user with a reason. It's better to catch invalid input before it hits the database, rather than coding business logic into the DB

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `CHECK` constraint to your column. The question is, how do you define 'a word'?

In a rather simplistic approach we could assume that words are 'split' by spaces. In MSSQL you'd then have to add a check like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_max_words] CHECK (Len(Replace([myField], N' ', N'')) > (Len([myField]) - 3))
```

When you try to insert or update a record and put the [myField] to 'test' it would pass, but if you set it to 'test test test test' it will fail because the number of spaces is 3 and our check will not let that pass.

Off course this approach is far from perfect. It does not consider double spaces, trailing spaces, etc...
From a practical point of view you probably want to write a function that counts the number of words according to your (elaborate) rules and then use that in the check.

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_max_words] CHECK (dbo.fn_number_of_words([myField] <= 3)
```

Comment: So what happens if a user types two spaces, or uses tabs? I'm not saying that to give input to improve your answer really, I'm just saying this because writing a "solid" check in the constraint might not be practical in T-SQL. This sort of check should really be done in another layer IMO.

Comment: @TT. I think the whole premise of limiting input by *words* is flawed from it's conception...

Comment: @Rob I would agree, but we don't know the requirements of the OP.

Comment: Like I said, it's far from perfect. You could 'catch' all of that in a function, but it's not going to be pretty nor fast. Then again, as TT says, we don't really know where the OP wants to go with this.